# A conversion of double integral to polar and evaluate, check

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, polar-coordinates

### Problem 1

Convert to polar form and solve

$$\int^{1}_{0}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}(1-x^2-y^2)\text{ dx dy}$$

$x^2+y^2-2y=0$

$x^2+(y-1)^2=1$

$x=rcos\theta$
$y=rsin\theta+1$

$r^2=1, r=1$

$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}(1-r^2cos^2\theta-(y^2cos^2\theta+1)) rdrd\theta$$
$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}(-r^3)drd\theta = -1/4{\pi}$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: is this correct? i do not have the answer to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You made an error when you substituted $y^2$. For the reference, the correct result is $\frac{2}{3} - \frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: Hey, i dont know why i cannot see that mistake? you mean when i plugged $ y= rsin\theta+1$ in $y^2$?

Comment: $y^2 = (r\sin\theta+1)^2$ and not what you did in the OP (if I'm reading this correctly).

Comment: ohh, so $(1-r^2cos\theta-(r^2sin^2\theta+2rsin\theta+1))$?
i get the integral of $-r^3-2r^2sin\theta$ ?

Comment: the result i got from the above is$-4/3 -pi/4$  so the plugging is still incorrect?